# Working with Double variables in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on a problem that requires to optimize a double variable. I wrote a simple code to try it out that tries to find a number given an upper bound ( maximize X while X < upper bound), but I get the following error that I did not understand :

> 2022-11-13 09:59:07,003 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (119), best score (-1init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.valuerange.buildin.primdouble.DoubleValueRange cannot be cast to class org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange.CountableValueRange (org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.valuerange.buildin.primdouble.DoubleValueRange and org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange.CountableValueRange are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.value.FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector.iterator(FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector.java:127)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.value.FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector.iterator(FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector.java:120)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.value.decorator.ReinitializeVariableValueSelector.iterator(ReinitializeVariableValueSelector.java:58)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.AbstractOriginalChangeIterator.createUpcomingSelection(AbstractOriginalChangeIterator.java:35)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.AbstractOriginalChangeIterator.createUpcomingSelection(AbstractOriginalChangeIterator.java:10)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:27)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacer$QueuedEntityPlacingIterator.createUpcomingSelection(QueuedEntityPlacer.java:45)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacer$QueuedEntityPlacingIterator.createUpcomingSelection(QueuedEntityPlacer.java:31)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:27)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:45)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:83)
> at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:193)
> at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:42)

The variable X has a range between 1 and 300, and the upper bound is an arbitrary 10.548

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner intentionally avoids working with doubles. [The documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#avoidFloatingPointNumbersInScoreCalculation) explains why, and also describes better ways of dealing with the issue.

That said, the exception you mention still shouldn't be happening, or there should be a more descriptive one. I'll eventually look into it. But my advice is to not count on doubles in your scoring function.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work with the alternative.

Comment: This isn't a double in the scoring function (like the removed HardSoftDoubleScore) , but a double in the value range. That should be fine (for cases like the investment portfolio example), but clearly `FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector`, disagrees...