# Optaplaner - Working with double variable in ConstraintProvider

Tags: optaplanner

Is there a way I can use `groupBy(ConstraintCollectors.sum(x))` such as *x* is a variable of type Double ?
I don't want to round it to *n* decimal pointes then multiply by *10^n*. I would like to use the Double variable as is.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419687/working-with-double-variables-in-optaplanner), OptaPlanner does not provide means of working with `double`.

That said, `ConstraintCollectors.sum()` is simple and if you look up its implementation, you should be able to implement a `double`-based one easily. Use with caution.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to work around the double, but in the end it gave me not so accurate results. I will try to check the implementation and see what I can do.

Comment: There's always `BigDecimal` - we support that out of the box. (It is a lot slower than `double` would be, though.)